# Websocket message interupts dynamic loading of ExtJS class

Tags: firefox, websocket, extjs, extjs4.1, http-get

in my ExtJS 4.1 application I use a websocket connection to remotely insantiate and control ExtJS classes from the server. The client is registered to websocket.onmessage and is waiting for incoming commands.

I defined a simple protocol for that. The server sends a "CREATE classname id". On client side I use Ext.create to instantiate the class. The server then can send commands via the websocket to the object. E.g. "DOSTUFF id". I'm using the dynamic loading mechnism of ExtJS.

In Chrome everything works fine.

The problem with Firefox is, that the second command message (DOSTUFF) is executed BEFORE the object has been created. This leads to an error because the object cannot be found. It seems that the second websocket commandmessage is executed before ExtJS has loaded the file via HTTP-GET.

In my world JavaScript is executed sequentially (I don't use webworkers). I think the call of Ext.create(..) should be executed synchronously with the HTTP-GET in background, shouldn't it?

Here is a "pseudo" trace output of my client application:

```
ExecuteCommand (Enter): CREATE ("MyClass", "1")
HTTP-GET "MyClass.js"
ExecuteCommand (Enter): DOSTUFF ("1")
ExecuteCommand (Error): DOSTUFF ("1"): Object not found
ExecuteCommand (Enter): CREATE ("MyClass", "1"): OK! Object created!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense. The GET request is async by default see Firefox doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

To avoid this issue check for object existence and if need be let the server know to resend in a few seconds, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as mentioned by DmitryB the HTTP-GET works asynchronous. After the XMLHttpRequest is sent, the control is passed to the next websocket.onmessage.

I solved this problem by using Ext.require with a callback function before I call Ext.create.

It looks something like that:

```
ExecuteCommand: CREATE ("MyClass", "1")
       Ext.require("MyClass", function(c) { 
            ExecuteCommand: DOSTUFF (c);
       }
```